# Moved file to another location in Apache NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to load to MySQL database using LOCAL INFILE however, i am having difficulties to move the files to a new location once they file has been successfully imported in MySql.
Below is a screen show of the process-flow.

[image: Process flow diagram of Nifi]
[image: FetchFile example]

My problem is:
I am managed to import/ load the database using the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE of MySql but the issue is when I am trying to move the successfully imported files to the correct directory. I fail to achieve so. The PutFile_sucess & PutFile_fail do not work as expected, so I decided to use: FetchFile and then I get an empty file when I say FetchFile it just creates it instead of moving the whole file.

I hope I have made myself clear, I would appreciate any inputs.

Comment: There's no error message? How about file permissions (`ls -l`)?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: There is no error. Just from the easy understanding..
As I said the xml is read and successfull loaded into the MySql..
the main difficult i am having is understanding the FlowFile processes..
If I use GetFile to get my files and then send them to ExecuteSQL the process will fail because GetFile just takes the file and puts it in memory, then LOAD LOCAL INFILE will fail to find the file because it is in memory.

Comment: check the provenance and see what is the event of failing files, not found or permission denied and if its failure please check nifi-app.log for exception

Answer (score 0):

if your issue is to remove the file once imported, you could just add a FetchFile processor somewhere after your sucess part and set the `Completion Strategy` to `Delete File`

However, better aproach will be to load the content of the file in Nifi then parse/split/process it and then (eventually regroup by batch) ingest the content in MySQL.

Could you maybe improve your question with informations like the format/structure/content of the file you're trying to load ?

Comment: Originally, we woud do:
` LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${XML_FILE_PATH}'
 INTO TABLE title CHARACTER SET binary
 LINES STARTING BY '<title>' TERMINATED BY '</title>'
 (@title)
 SET
 id = ExtractValue(@title, 'id'),
 text = ExtractValue(@title, 'text');`

the problem, is that when converting the process from script to apache-nifi format, then:
doing this::
` LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${filename}'
 INTO TABLE title `

fails and the reason is because Java throws NO FILE FOUND, which is coming from MySQL. We experience this error when using GetFile, ExecuteSQL..

Comment: However, when we changed to ListFile, ExecuteSQL no problems for that.. My question is about Apache-Nifi handling file resources when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE with MySQL.
If Apache-Nifi has ingested the file in memory, then why when I do::
` LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${filename}'
 INTO TABLE title `

The above load data local fails.. And when I do::
` LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '${absolute.path}/${filename}'
 INTO TABLE title ` 
_This runs sucessfully_

I am sure it has something to do with my understanding of Apache-Nifi and MySQL %LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE% function.

Comment: Anyways I have been working with Apache Nifi, for like 2 days, we are still trying to learn/test and understad more of it..
And i will keep on investigating further..

Comment: @NoelAlexMakumuli if it fails when you just change from relative path to absolute path, it indicates that your current directory is not the directory you believe you are in. When you pass `${filename}` to the ExecuteSQL processor, it will read the attribute "filename" on the current flowfile and replace `'${filename}` before sending the sql statement. MySQL will receive something like "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE myfile.xml" and will look on disk in current directory of MySQL.

Comment: Another way to do this more NiFI style would be to GetFile -> combination of SplitXML/ExtractText/EvaluateXpath to put your data in attributes (${field1},${field2}...) -> ExecuteSQL to insert your datas (INSERT INTO table (aaa,bbb) VALUES ${field1}, ${field2})

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
I will investigate how SplitXML/ExtractText/EvaluateXPath works and see if it can fit my process.
I will definitely give feedback.